# How to communicate with a physical printer and print on button click

Tags: asp.net, printing

How can I develop a web application where the user clicks a button and on button Click it communicates with a physical printer and prints out.
Needs to run on ASP.NET.

Comment: how about adding a javascript snippet on the page like <button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>

Comment: Thats the thing @kishoreVM it needs to communicate with a printer but this window.print will open a pop-up where the user needs to click more buttons, thats not what i need, more like activeX i need a way that the user can just click the button and print away, since this is to print more then 2k papers a day. And i can´t use activeX because it needs to be on a cross-browser basis.

Comment: I think its not possible unless settings are changed on the browser where its gonna be used . chrome has setting called --kiosk-printing (this command line param needs to be set  before launching chrome ) other browsers may have a different name for this setting.

Comment: like the one mentioned in this link https://support.custom-gateway.com/portal/en/kb/articles/setting-up-auto-print-for-labels-in-google-chrome

Comment: @kishoreVM i looked it up, the  disable-print-preview flag that they tell you to deActivate doesen´t even exist anymore, this might be a dead control for chrome?